# Multiple configuration properties in spring boot @Autowired one of the properties are null

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I am new to spring, I have following boot application classes. I am trying to connect to AWS SQS from Spring boot application. The code is as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties ({ApplicationProperties.class, AwsProperties.class})
public class Application{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

ApplicationProperties.java

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="midb")
public class ApplicationProperties {

    private String keyStore;
    private String keyStorePassword;

// getter and setters
}

AwsProperties.java

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="aws")
public class AwsProperties {

    private String sqsEndpoint;
    private String accessKey;
    private String secretKey;
// getters and setters
}


@Configuration
@EnableJms
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AwsProperties.class)
public class JmsConfig {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JmsConfig.class);


    @Autowired
    private AwsProperties awsProperties;

    @Autowired
    private SQSListener sqsListener;
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //System.out.println("================== " + awsProperties.toString() + "==================");// End point:"+endpoint);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSQSClient createSQSClient() {

        AmazonSQSClient amazonSQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(awsProperties.getAccessKey(), awsProperties.getSecretKey()));
        amazonSQSClient.setEndpoint(awsProperties.getSqsEndpoint());
        amazonSQSClient.createQueue(awsProperties.getSqsQueueName());
        return amazonSQSClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer jmsListenerContainer() {
        SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
                .withAWSCredentialsProvider(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withEndpoint(awsProperties.getSqsEndpoint()).withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10).build();
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer dmlc = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        dmlc.setConnectionFactory(sqsConnectionFactory);
        dmlc.setDestinationName(awsProperties.getSqsQueueName());
        dmlc.setMessageListener(sqsListener);
        return dmlc;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate createJMSTemplate() {
        SQSConnectionFactory sqsConnectionFactory = SQSConnectionFactory.builder()
                .withAWSCredentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider).withEndpoint(awsProperties.getSqsEndpoint())
                .withNumberOfMessagesToPrefetch(10).build();
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(sqsConnectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(awsProperties.getSqsQueueName());
        jmsTemplate.setDeliveryPersistent(false);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    private final AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSCredentialsProvider() {
        @Override
        public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
            return new BasicAWSCredentials(awsProperties.getAccessKey(), awsProperties.getSecretKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void refresh() {
        }
    };
}
```

When Maven builds, I get the following error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'createSQSClient' defined in class path
>   resource [io/bigbear/midb/sqs/JmsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via
>   factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient]: Factory
>   method 'createSQSClient' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Access key cannot be null.

Comment: The key is in your error message: `Access key cannot be null`. Looks like you need to (at least) fix `AwsProperties.getAccessKey()` so it doesn't return null.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but it seems your `awsProperties.getAccessKey()` returns null.